# Python - List appending getting slower?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, append

I have a problem with my Python code. I am processing a big (3.5gb) JSON file that contains scores, and I need it in chunks of 21984 scores (which is all the scores for one query). The code works fine, but my testset is 4000 queries. The first 10 go fast but after that it exponentially increases time to calculate this part of the code. So after 5 hours i'm on 500 queries. The prints were for logging, and it seems that the problem lies in the translating or appending the lines to the list. Does anyone know how to make this faster or sees what caused it to get slower?

```
def getscorebatch(number):
    print('Creating Batch..')
    batch_temp = list()
    with open(json_file_name, 'r') as FileObj:
        print("Creating slice...")
        lines_gen = islice(FileObj, (21894 * number), ((21894 * number) + 21894))
        print("Appending slice...")
        for line in lines_gen:
            line = line.translate({ord(c): None for c in ':",}{ \n'})
            batch_temp.append(line)
    return batch_temp
```

UPDATE: I tried to implement your suggestions, and it is way faster! Thank you so much. Im fairly new to generators, so what i do not understand is now, how do I get the correct chunk the code? This will give me the first chunk everytime..

```
def generator(file_to_read):
c = 0
while c < 21894:
    data = file_to_read.readline()
    c += 1
    if not data:
        break
    yield data



def getscorebatch(number):
    print('Creating Batch..')
    batch_temp = [0]*22000
    with open(json_file_name, 'r') as FileObj:
        gen_file = generator(FileObj)
        batch_temp = [line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", REMOVE)) for line in gen_file]
        print(len(batch_temp))
    return batch_temp
```

Comment: Can you please fix the strange syntax (e.g. indentation)?

Comment: You may be better off using an external library such as pandas, which has a `read_json` method. (C)Python alone tends not to be the best tool for working with large datasets.

Comment: Edit: I already tried to disable garbage collecting before appending and enable it after.

Comment: @9769953 you mean to load the lines in the panda dataframe? Because I cannot load the JSON as a whole because of the size

Comment: @LPinter Can you please post the correct code, this one is missing a quote and has indentation issue.

Comment: Have a look at the `chunksize` parameter for `read_json`; perhaps that can help you.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary fixed it, sorry

Comment: I take it you're calling the `getscorebatch` function in a loop? If so, that would mean that you're repeatedly opening the file and discarding thousands of lines before hitting the spot where the islice begins. You'd be better off keeping the file object open and continuing to read from where you left off.

Comment: @Aran-Fey That is what i had before, but for some reason the index shifts and produces the wrong score file when i do that..

Comment: I would recommend to use `re.sub()` with a regular expression compiled outside of the loop instead of `translate` with on-the-fly dictionary comprehension.

Comment: I am pretty convinced that the slowdown reflects you running out of memory and your computer starting to madly swap to disk, or else the slices to get the line. Without seeing more of the code, I hope you're not retaining information on the batches in memory... And if you're processing all the data, why open and slice and close all the time, once per batch? Make a generator that will read the file and yield batches as they are found. Finally, is that a JSON file or JSONL file? Sounds like a JSONL file (which is good, 3.5gb of JSON sounds horrible to deal with).

Comment: @Amadan About the memory, i am using a virtual machine with 3gb ram so that could be an issue. I will try to use a generator, thanks for the tip. It is a JSONL file indeed!